# Python: Error with opencv packaged with pyinstaller

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

*-> with python version 3.6 - I can't change this version*

I packaged my code, which imports opencv, thanks to pyinstaller on a redhat RHEL7.7. The package is correctly done and the executable works fine on the same machine.

When running this executable on another machine (redhat RHEL7.1), it raises the following error:

```
File "cv2/__init__.py" line 5, in <module>
ImportError: libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_poll_for_reply64
```

Can anyone helps? tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libX11 is a graphical server that is not mandatory for my app. Then, the use of opencv-python-headless instead of opencv-python fixed this issue.